# Flutter Hive Adapter registration problem

Tags: flutter, hive

I have problem with Hive adatpter registration.
I have followed few online tutorials how to do it right.

I always get this error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: () => Null. Did you forget to register an adapter?
```

and no, I do not forgot to register an adatper ;/
Here is my class for custom object:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'reagent_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class ReagentModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
   int id;
  @HiveField(1)
   String reagentName; //nazwa odczynnika
  @HiveField(2)
   double mass; //gramatura
  @HiveField(3)
   String
      measurement; //oznaczenie miary do gramatury ^ Litry gramy kilogramy itp
  @HiveField(4)
   DateTime date;
  @HiveField(5)
   Function issue; //wydanie
  @HiveField(6)
   Function deleteFun;
  @HiveField(7)
   String financing;
  @HiveField(8)
   double price;
  @HiveField(9)
   String name; //imie kogos?
  @HiveField(10)
   Function add;

  ReagentModel(
      {required this.id,
      required this.reagentName,
      required this.mass,
      required this.measurement,
      required this.date,
      required this.issue,
      required this.deleteFun,
      required this.financing,
      required this.price,
      required this.name,
      required this.add});
}
```

Main:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(ReagentModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<ReagentModel>('Reagent');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Generated Adapter:

```
part of 'reagent_model.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class ReagentModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ReagentModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  ReagentModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return ReagentModel(
        id: fields[0] as int,
        reagentName: fields[1] as String,
        mass: fields[2] as double,
        measurement: fields[3] as String,
        date: fields[4] as DateTime,
        issue: fields[5] as Function,
        deleteFun: fields[6] as Function,
        financing: fields[7] as String,
        price: fields[8] as double,
        name: fields[9] as String,
        add: fields[10] as Function,
        );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, ReagentModel obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(11)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.id)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.reagentName)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.mass)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.measurement)
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..write(obj.date)
      ..writeByte(5)
      ..write(obj.issue)
      ..writeByte(6)
      ..write(obj.deleteFun)
      ..writeByte(7)
      ..write(obj.financing)
      ..writeByte(8)
      ..write(obj.price)
      ..writeByte(9)
      ..write(obj.name)
      ..writeByte(10)
      ..write(obj.add);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is ReagentModelAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

And finaly, function that tried to save object in database:

```
Future _function() async {
    final reagent = ReagentModel(
        id: 2,
        reagentName: 'name',
        mass: 1,
        measurement: 'g',
        date: DateTime.now(),
        issue: () {},
        deleteFun: () {},
        financing: 's',
        price: 1,
        name: 'a',
        add: () {},
        );
    final box = Boxes.getReagents();
    box.add(reagent);
  }
```

and also this boxes class (I am not realy sure what it changes in my code, but it was on tutorials so here it is):

```
class Boxes {
  static Box<ReagentModel> getReagents() => Hive.box<ReagentModel>('Reagent');
}
```

I would be very grateful for any information or up-to-date sources

Comment: Try to avoid using the Boxes class and access the Box in the same widget you are using it calling `Hive.box<ReagentModel>('Reagent')`, declare a variable call `Box<ReagentModel> reagent;` and initialize it in the initState like this `reagent = Hive.box<ReagentModel>('Reagent');`

Comment: make sure the box has nothing else than that type, it could be caused if the box has other types than the type you open the box with

Comment: @WilsonToribio, I have change it as you said, but still getting error.

Comment: @Gwhyyy is there any option to check that?

Comment: set a breakpoint before the box declaration, and see it from the debug side, or just print it in the console and check it